# Node.js + mysql data is not entering into database

Tags: mysql, node.js

In my node app i am trying to insert data into mysql databse. I am Following this tutorial

"http://www.tutorialindustry.com/node-js-mysql-tutorial-for-beginners"

My code:

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, mysql = require('mysql')
, path = require('path');
var app = express();
// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3002);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function( req, res) {
res.render('index');
});
//connect to mysql database
/*var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host : '127.0.0.1',
user : 'root',
password : 'root',
database : 'nodejsmysql'
});
connection.connect();*/

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'nodejsmysql',
  debug : true,
})
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if ( !err ) {
        console.log("Connected to MySQL");
    } else if ( err ) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
connection.query('select * from nodejs', function(err, docs) {
res.render('users', {users: docs});
});
});
// Add a new User
app.get("/users/new", function (req, res) {
res.render("new");
});
// Save the Newly created User
app.post("/users", function (req, res) {
var fname=req.body.fname;
var lname=req.body.lname;
console.log("qqqqqqqqqq")
connection.query('INSERT INTO nodejs (fname, lname) VALUES (? , ?);' , [fname, lname], function(err, docs) {
if (err) res.json(err);
res.redirect('users');
});
});
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Not throwing any error.but the datas are not entering into database.

Comment: Does the Add New User page redirect?

Comment: Yes is redtirected..Also i entered the value and clicking "AddNewUser" ,but that entry is not entered into mysql database..

Comment: You also created a new database/tables? I copied the above code (along with following the rest of the tutorial), and it works fine for me. By "does that page redirect", I meant, once you click "Add New User" (after filling out a first/last names), it actually redirects to the "Showing All Users" page, correct? Just trying to rule out a template issue that I had.

Comment: @making3 thanks for your valuable time..I Created a database ,when i click "AddNewUser" its not redirecting..When i click "Addnewuser" nothing happens.. Help me to solve this..

Comment: I am the author of the tutorial you have mentioned here, I apologise for troubling you, especially Subburaj. The site's theme has some problem, I have updated the tutorial and added the code for the tutorial separately. @making3: I will try to do better.

Comment: can you update the tutorial aacharya, I have problems with middleware no longer bundled with express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue due to the formatting of the tutorial you are using. Specifically speaking, for the `views/new.jade` file, some indention is **required**, otherwise the form will not be submitted. View how the below template is intended:

```
h1 Add new User

form(method="POST" , action="/users")
    p FirstName:
    input#title(type="text" , name="fname")
    p LastName:
    input#body(type="text" , name="lname")

    p: button(type="submit") Add New User
```

Views/index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    p Welcome to nodejs mysql tutorial
    p
    a(href='/users') Show All users
```

Views/users.jade:

```
h1 Showing All Users

ul
- each user in users
    li User FirstName: #{user.fname}
    li User LastName: #{user.lname}
hr

a(href="users/new") Add New User
br
a(href="/") Home
```

If you want to know more, it looks like the [Jade website](http://jade-lang.com/) has some useful information/tutorials.

Comment: Thanks making3..Now its redirecting..But showing some problem in users.jade..Can you please post that users.jade file with proper indention..

Comment: Thanks a lot man..Now its working..But why that tutorial website not guiding properly...Also whether its possible to convert that output(all users) to show in json format..Guide me if have some idea on this..

Comment: Yeah I wasn't a fan of that tutorial..His formatting is off and he lacks explaining a lot of basic fundamentals. As far as the json goes, I think you can remove `ul`, replace `li User FirstName/LastName: #..` with `span #{..`, and wrap the `span`'s with mustaches ({}) to your liking. I'm fairly new to jade, but that seemed to work for me.